# What does "put big bucks behind its growth initiatives" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "they have enough cash to turn their growth goal into reality"?

With McDonald’s's scale and hefty cash flow, it's able to **put big bucks behind its growth initiatives**. Just look at the success of all-day breakfast, which helped usher in six straight quarters of comparable sales growth at the chain while most other restaurants stumbled, or its McCafe business, which has grown to $4 billion in annual U.S. sales.

SOURCE: https://www.bloomberg.com/gadfly/articles/2017-03-01/mcdonald-s-investor-day-copying-starbucks-is-smart

Answer (score 1):

It means the **growth initiative** will **require investment** and McDonald's, because they have the financial resources available, they can make the investment, eventhough the **investment will be a lot of money** (*put big bucks behind*).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically.  It means "they have A LOT OF cash to TRY TO turn their growth goal into reality."